# "Unable to get Filesystem for path" error when training neural network on google cloud

Tags: python, csv, google-app-engine, terminal, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud to train a neural network on the cloud like in the following example:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-classify-images-with-tensorflow-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow

To start I set the following to environmental variables:

```
PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)")
BUCKET_NAME=${PROJECT_ID}-mlengine
```

I then uploaded my training and evaluation data, both csv's with the names eval_set.csv and train_set.csv to Google cloud storage with the following command:

```
gsutil cp -r data gs://$BUCKET_NAME
```

I then verified that these two csv files where in the polar-terminal-160506-mlengine/data directory on my Google Cloud storage.

I then did the following environmental variable assignments

```
# Assign appropriate values.
PROJECT=$(gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)")
JOB_ID="flowers_${USER}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
GCS_PATH="${BUCKET}/${USER}/${JOB_ID}"
DICT_FILE=gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dict.txt
```

Before trying to preprocess my evaluation data like so:

```
# Preprocess the eval set.
python trainer/preprocess.py \
  --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
  --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
  --cloud
```

Sadly, this runs for a bit and then crashes outputting the following error:

```
ValueError: Unable to get the Filesystem for path gs://polar-terminal-160506-mlengine/data/eval_set.csv
```

This doesn't seem possible as I have confirmed with my eyes via my Google Cloud Storage console that eval_set.csv is stored at this location. Is this perhaps a permissions issue or something I am not seeing?

Edit:

I have found the cause of this run time error to be from a certain line in the trainer.preprocess.py file. The line is this one:

```
read_input_source = beam.io.ReadFromText(
      opt.input_path, strip_trailing_newlines=True)
```

Seems like a pretty good clue but I am still not really sure what is going on. When I google "beam.io.ReadFromText  ValueError: Unable to get the Filesystem for path" nothing relevant at all appears which is a bit odd. Thoughts?

Answer (score 13):

It looks like your apache-beam library installation might be incomplete.

try `pip install apache-beam[gcp]`

It allows apache beam to access files stored on Google Cloud Storage.

Apache Beam package available [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apache-beam)

Comment: hi, trying to solve the same problem here. I couldn't find this library in PyPi: `no matches found: apache-beam[gcp]`

Comment: @LucasShen     It appears it is available on Pypi [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apache-beam). Perhaps your python version is not compatible with the package?

Answer (score 2):

Just as Jean-Christophe described, I believe your installation is incomplete.

The `apache-beam` package doesn't include all the stuff to read/write from GCP. To get all that, as well as the runner for being able to deploy your pipeline to CloudDataflow (the `DataRunner`), you'll need to install it via `pip`.

```
pip install google-cloud-dataflow
```

This is how I was able to resolve the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install apache_beam[gcp]`. This will help you.