# Apache Beam Error: Unable to get file system for GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I'm trying to write to GCS bucket via Beam (and TF Transform). But I keep getting the following error:

> ValueError: Unable to get the Filesystem for path [...]

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124229/unable-to-get-filesystem-for-path-error-when-training-neural-network-on-google) and some other sources suggest that I need to `pip install aache-beam[gcp]` to get a different variant of Apache Beam that works with GCP.

So, I tried changing the `setup.py` of my training package as:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['apache_beam[gcp]==2.14.0', 'tensorflow-ranking', 'tensorflow_transform==0.14.0']
```

which didn't help. I also tried adding the following to the beginning of my code:

```
subprocess.check_call('pip uninstall apache-beam'.split())
subprocess.check_call('pip install apache-beam[gcp]'.split())
```

which didn't work either.

The logs of the failed GCP job is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10ztWvUA3-Ufyw-6wGNmhbOe3-3c2NUcWECt_pxkSaig/edit?usp=sharing). The traceback and the error message appear on row 276.

I should mention that running the same code using Beam's DirectRunner and writing the outputs to local disk runs fine. But I'm now trying to switch to DataflowRunner.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that you need to uninstall `google-cloud-dataflow` in addition to installing `apache-beam` with the `gcp` option. I guess this happens because `google-cloud-dataflow` is installed on GCP instances by default. Not sure if the same would be true on other platforms like AWS. But anyway, here are the commands I used:

```
pip uninstall -y google-cloud-dataflow
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
```

I noticed this in the very first cell of [this notebook] (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/10_recommend/wals_tft.ipynb).